# Java if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

How come the last line of this code is not picking up the string `filename` in the code?

```
if (ressound == R.id.sound1) {
    String filename = "sound1" + ".ogg";
} else {
    String filename = "sound1" + ".ogg";
}
boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
if (!exists) { new File(path).mkdirs(); }   

FileOutputStream save;
try { 
    save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
```

Comment: You'll want to fix your indentation too as proper indentation and formatting makes it much easier for both you and us to debug your code.

Comment: Oddly you are setting filename to "sound1"+".ogg" in both cases, so why have an if-else at all?

Comment: What I think is even more odd is that you seem to concatenate two strings where you could simply put it into one. The way you are doing it now calls a `StringBuilder` internally which would not be required if you'd put it as one string like this `String filename = "sound1.ogg"`.

Answer (score 14):

You're declaring the variable in the scope of the if respectively else branch. Out of this scope the variable is not accessible.

Use this instead:

```
String filename;
    if (ressound == R.id.sound1) {
           filename="sound1"+".ogg";
       } else{
            filename="sound1"+".ogg";
       }
             boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
             if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

             FileOutputStream save;
             try { 
              save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
```

Comment: btw I see now that bot branches are doing the same thing. Is that maybe the problem``

Comment: You don't need to initialize `filename` to `""` as long as you assign it a value in both branches (the `if` and `else` blocks). You can use `String filename;` alone. Seeing an initialized value would make me expect a case where it doesn't get changed.

Comment: Yes thats true. I'll change it

Answer (score 3):

Your code as it is won't even compile as both `filename` variables you've declared are gone out of scope where you create the FileOutputStream.

I would do this:

```
private String getFilename() {
    if (ressound == R.id.sound1) {
        return "sound1"+".ogg";
    }
    return "sound1"+".ogg";
}
```

And then call it from your other method:

```
boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
if (!exists){ new File(path).mkdirs(); }   

FileOutputStream save;
try { 
    save = new FileOutputStream(path+getFilename());
```

As I've said in the comment above I don't know why you assign the same value to filename in both cases, as in `getFilename()` *always* returns `"sound1.ogg"`. Maybe that was your bug but I left it as you have it.

Comment: also, thanks for the alternative. i just copy pasted the lines from trying to run the if statements. so the variables were the same. obv, they are suppose to be different. thanks a lot